# How to sort an array of objects correctly by an object's alphanumeric name value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, alphanumeric

I am trying to sort an array of objects by the name field but the ordering is wrong.

The order I am getting is [1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21, 3]

Instead of [1, 2, 3, .... 10, 11, 20, 21]

It is sorting but putting 10 ahead of 2

Here is the code I am currently using.

```js
const arr = [
    
    {
        "name": "Action 10",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 11",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 2",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 20",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 21",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 3",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 4",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 5",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 6",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    },
    {
        "name": "Action 1",
        "color": "transparent",
        "type": "components"
    }
]

function sorter(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
}

console.log(arr.sort(sorter));
```

Comment: This is because it's sorting by string (not numerically) so "10" comes before "2".  If you want a numeric sort, you'll need to split the strings to get the # and sort on that.  Could the "name" have any other pattern than "Action #"?

Comment: @AndyJamesN ... From all the provided answers / approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Nope it is clear now and all solutions work. I am just curious.. is there a reason your solution is better than the reg ex or other solution? I am not entirely sure which would be considered the best answer.

Comment: @AndyJamesN ... as mostly the answer is ... _"It depends."_ . For the OP's special use case of an **over and over repeating pattern** of just a **single _same_ word** part like `'Action'` as in `"Action 1"` and a **_sole_ digit sequence** part like `'21'` as in `"Action 21"` the regex based solutions which are just after matching digits via `/\d+/` and parsing and sorting it are equal. But any of these approaches fail already for a lowercase `"action 10"` versus the original `"Action 10"` and of cause for any word other than `'Action'` within an item's `name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could give the [`numeric` sorting option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#numeric_sorting) of [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) a try ...

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "Action 10", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 11", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 2", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 20", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 21", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 3", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 4", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 5", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 6", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}, {
  name: "Action 1", color: "transparent", type: "components"
}];

function sorter(a, b) {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
}
console.log(arr.sort(sorter));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering is correct. The string "Action 10" collates greater than `Action 1` and less than `Action 2`, because string comparison is done on a character by character basis.

The algorithm for string comparision is found here: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.8.5

> [If] both px and py are Strings
>
> - If *py* is a prefix of *px*, return `false`. (A String value *p* is a prefix of String value *q* if *q* can be the result of concatenating *p* and some other String *r*. Note that any String is a prefix of itself, because *r* may be the empty String.)
> - If *px* is a prefix of *py*, return `true`.
>
> Let *k* be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the character at position *k* within *px* is different from the character at position *k* within *py*. (There must be such a *k*, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)
>
> - Let *m* be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position *k* within *px*.
> - Let *n* be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position *k* within *py*.
> - If *m* < *n*, return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`.

Or, as a javascript function, the expression `str1 < str2` is evaluated as if this function were invoked (not that anybody sane would implement the algorithm as described in the spec):

```js
function lt( px, py ) {
    const prefixOf = (x,y) => x.slice(0,y.length) === y;

    if ( prefixOf(px,py) ) return false;
    if ( prefixOf(py,px) ) return true;

    let k = 0 ;
    while ( px[k] === py[k] ) {
        ++k;
    }
 
    m = px.charCodeAt(k);
    n = py.charCodeAt(k);

    return m < n ? true : false;
  }
```

If you want to order things according to the ***semantic meaning*** of `name`, you'll need to partition the string into a list of its non-numeric and numeric segments, convert the numeric bits into numbers, and then compare the segments in order from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
const sorter = (a, b) => +a.name.match(/\d+/) - +b.name.match(/\d+/);
```

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [{"name": "Action 10","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 11","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 2","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 20","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 21","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 3","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 4","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 5","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 6","color": "transparent","type": "components"}, {"name": "Action 1","color": "transparent","type": "components"}]

function sorter(a, b) {
    return +a.name.match(/\d+/)[0] - +b.name.match(/\d+/)[0];
}

console.log(arr.sort(sorter));
```